# Prediction through pickle dump - ValueError: could not convert string to float:

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, svm

I am trying to get the prediction values through pickled dump by passing a dump of unseen data through csv.
I am getting the below error and i am unable to proceed further. Appreciate any quick workaround.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-19-c7877b0e4ecc> in <module>
     40     X_test = df_a1['ML_Description'].astype(str)
     41     y_test = df_a1['Classification'].astype(str)
---> 42     ODP_pred_gs_cv = ODP_Model.predict(X_test)
     43     df_a1['Classification'] = ODP_pred_gs_cv
     44     df_a1.to_csv('TOC_IP_ODP_ML_New_Validation_Results.csv',columns=header, index=True)

C:\Programs\Miniconda3_x64\envs\jup369\lib\site-packages\sklearn\linear_model\base.py in predict(self, X)
    287             Predicted class label per sample.
    288         """
--> 289         scores = self.decision_function(X)
    290         if len(scores.shape) == 1:
    291             indices = (scores > 0).astype(np.int)

C:\Programs\Miniconda3_x64\envs\jup369\lib\site-packages\sklearn\linear_model\base.py in decision_function(self, X)
    263                                  "yet" % {'name': type(self).__name__})
    264 
--> 265         X = check_array(X, accept_sparse='csr')
    266 
    267         n_features = self.coef_.shape[1]

C:\Programs\Miniconda3_x64\envs\jup369\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py in check_array(array, accept_sparse, accept_large_sparse, dtype, order, copy, force_all_finite, ensure_2d, allow_nd, ensure_min_samples, ensure_min_features, warn_on_dtype, estimator)
    494             try:
    495                 warnings.simplefilter('error', ComplexWarning)
--> 496                 array = np.asarray(array, dtype=dtype, order=order)
    497             except ComplexWarning:
    498                 raise ValueError("Complex data not supported\n"

C:\Programs\Miniconda3_x64\envs\jup369\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\_asarray.py in asarray(a, dtype, order)
     83 
     84     """
---> 85     return array(a, dtype, copy=False, order=order)
     86 
     87 

ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'PrimaryAccountRESManagementTOCI&PCrossFunctionTOC&Infra&PlatformGroupTechnologyADRG232381ADRGA3VDIWorkspaceREADONLYADSamuraiA3VDIWorkspaceREADONLYapp_Global_pooledvdi_vOmega_itaw_userapp_Global_pooledvdi_vOmega_itaw_userADSamuraiARPA3vO'
```

**Here is my code:**

Below is my code and i am reading a new dataset and there are no spaces in the Description column which i am using to predict. I have verified and i removed all spaces but still i am getting the above error
Any help or workaround is much appreciated.

```
import warnings
import matplotlib.pyplot as pp
import numpy as np
import datetime
import re
import csv
import pandas as pd
import datetime
from sqlalchemy import types, create_engine
import pickle
import warnings
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report, confusion_matrix
import glob, os    
warnings.filterwarnings("ignore")

print ("Import latest ODP Entilements dataset - Start :",str(datetime.datetime.now()))

Classification = np.nan
df1 = pd.read_csv("TOC_IP_ODP_ML_New_Validation_Dataset.csv",encoding='iso-8859-1')
##df1['ML_Description'] = pd.to_numeric(df1['ML_Description'], downcast='float')

df1['Classification'] = Classification
header = ['Source4point','Source7point','SourceSystem','subsystem lookup (ARP)','DISPLAY_NAME_1','DISPLAYABLE_NAME','EXTENDED2','OriginalSourceSystem','ML_Description','Classification']
a1 = df1['ML_Index'].count()

## Pass the above datasets through the pickled ML models to predict the classifications

if a1 > 0:
    df1.to_csv("TOC_IP_ODP_ML_New_Validation_Dataset.csv", index=False)
    ODP_Model = pickle.load(open('TOCIP_ODP_ML_FModel.pkl', 'rb'), encoding='iso-8859-1')
    df_a1 = pd.read_csv('TOC_IP_ODP_ML_New_Validation_Dataset.csv',encoding='iso-8859-1', index_col="ML_Index")
    X_test = df_a1['ML_Description'].astype(str)
    y_test = df_a1['Classification'].astype(str)
    ODP_pred_gs_cv = ODP_Model.predict(X_test)
    df_a1['Classification'] = ODP_pred_gs_cv
    df_a1.to_csv('TOC_IP_ODP_ML_New_Validation_Results.csv',columns=header, index=True)
    print ("Entitlements Data has been passed through ODP ML Model & Classifications generated")
    print ("Entitlements count : ",a1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Normally machine learning model cannot work with string but you have converted your features and output to string

```
X_test = df_a1['ML_Description'].astype(str)
y_test = df_a1['Classification'].astype(str)
```